# some Linkedin oauth 2 login integrations javascript example

Tags: javascript, integration, linkedin-api

Suddenly it's me, but I didn't know how to integrate linkedin oauth 2, I got here:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function callLinkeding() {
         var result = {};
         fetch("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&" +
               "client_id=77ho2u1ye0hpg1" + "&" +
               "redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Faccount%2Flogin" + "&" +
               "scope=r_emailaddress")
             .then(function(res) {
                 if (res) { // ok
                     console.log('Linkedin [  OK  ]');
                 }
                 else {
                     console.log('Linkedin [ Warning ]');
                 }
                 console.log(res.url);
             })
             .then(function(blob) {
                 console.log("Linkedin [ Fail ]");
             });
     }
     callLinkeding();
</script>
```

[this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication?context=linkedin/consumer/context#) is not the best for me.

But the vanilla javascript respond me next:

> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/login-success?app_id=30823693&auth_type=AC&flow=%7B%22creationTime%22%3A1597171345409%2C%22scope%22%3A%22r_emailaddress%22%2C%22appId%22%3A30823693%2C%22authorizationType%22%3A%22OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE%22%2C%22redirectUri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Faccount%2Flogin%22%2C%22currentStage%22%3A%22LOGIN_SUCCESS%22%2C%22currentSubStage%22%3A0%2C%22authFlowName%22%3A%22generic-permission-list%22%7D

Please **could some one tell me the next steps for integrate the linkedin login** inside my test web site? I'm over https with CORS enable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official javascript SDK - https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk/tutorials/tutorial

Comment: The SDK is not supported anymore since 2019. The recommended approach is to use OAuth 2.0 and LinkedIn's API.
https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates